# Multidimensional array-document.write issues-javascript

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

When i do document.write for a javascript variable,

```
  var abcd = [["165q",1],["160q",6],["161q",7],["162q",7],["163q",8],["164q",5]];
   document.write(abcd);
```

I get the result as

```
165q,1,160q,6,161q,7,162q,7,163q,8,164q,5
```

But when i pass a similar data through a variable to abcd,and when i do document.write then result is exact multidimensional array.code below

```
function radar_avg_one(one_chart_result) {
var abcd = one_chart_result;
 document.write(abcd);
document.write(one_chart_result);
}
```

Result of
document.write(one_chart_result);

is `[["165q",1],["160q",6],["161q",7],["162q",7],["163q",8],["164q",5]]`

Result of
document.write(abcd);

is `[["165q",1],["160q",6],["161q",7],["162q",7],["163q",8],["164q",5]]`

I cant understand when its explicitly assigned why it gives a different result.Main issue is that google radar chart is working only when i hardcode values like that :(

Comment: I just tried all that in console and got the same output for each one

Comment: Perhaps `one_chart_result` is a string instead of an array? Insert `alert(typeof one_chart_result);` to be sure. It should state "object" if it's an array.

Comment: @Christoph yeah ur correctl.it gives string as result.any way i can convert it to array.and make it behave same as abcd.Sorry i am very new to scripts :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JSON.stringify([["165q",1],["160q",6],["161q",7],["162q",7],["163q",8],["164q",5]]);
```

with JSON you can stringify and parse objects and arrays in javascript to and from text in a way that data can be reused.

the result will be:

```
"[[\"165q\",1],[\"160q\",6],[\"161q\",7],[\"162q\",7],[\"163q\",8],[\"164q\",5]]"
```

with this:

```
JSON.parse("[[\"165q\",1],[\"160q\",6],[\"161q\",7],[\"162q\",7],[\"163q\",8],[\"164q\",5]]");
```

the result will be:

```
[["165q",1],["160q",6],["161q",7],["162q",7],["163q",8],["164q",5]]
```

wich is a true array

for JSON support in browsers without native json you shall add this to your site:
https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js

with:

```
String([["165q",1],["160q",6],["161q",7],["162q",7],["163q",8],["164q",5]]);
```

and:

```
[["165q",1],["160q",6],["161q",7],["162q",7],["163q",8],["164q",5]].toString();
```

you will get this as result:

```
"165q,1,160q,6,161q,7,162q,7,163q,8,164q,5"
```